# Distances to coordinates

Tags: code-golf, geometry

There are *n* people on a 2D plane. Using distances between them we're going to find their positions. To get a unique answer you must make four assumptions:

1. There are at least 3 people.
2. The first person is at position (0, 0).
3. The second person is at position (x, 0) for some x > 0.
4. The third person is at position (x, y) for some y > 0.

So your challenge is to write a program or function that given a 2D array of distances (where `D[i][j]` gives the distance between person `i` and `j`) returns a list of their coordinates. Your answer must be accurate to at least 6 significant figures. Shortest solution in bytes wins.

---

#### Examples

```
[[0.0, 3.0, 5.0], [3.0, 0.0, 4.0], [5.0, 4.0, 0.0]]

=>

[[0.0, 0.0], [3.0, 0.0], [3.0, 4.0]]


[[0.0, 0.0513, 1.05809686, 0.53741028, 0.87113533], [0.0513, 0.0, 1.0780606,
0.58863967, 0.91899559], [1.05809686, 1.0780606, 0.0, 0.96529704,
1.37140397], [0.53741028, 0.58863967, 0.96529704, 0.0, 0.44501955],
[0.87113533, 0.91899559, 1.37140397, 0.44501955, 0.0]]

=>

[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0513, 0.0], [-0.39, 0.9836], [-0.5366, 0.0295], [-0.8094, -0.3221]]


[[0.0, 41.9519, 21.89390815, 108.37048253, 91.40006121, 49.35063671,
82.20983622, 83.69080223, 80.39436793, 86.5204431, 91.24484876, 22.32327813,
99.5351474, 72.1001264, 71.98278813, 99.8621559, 104.59071383, 108.61475753,
94.91576952, 93.20212636], [41.9519, 0.0, 24.33770482, 144.67214389,
132.28290899, 49.12079288, 85.34321428, 117.39095617, 103.60848008,
79.67795144, 69.52024038, 42.65007733, 105.60007249, 110.50120501,
89.92218111, 60.03623019, 133.61394005, 76.26668715, 130.54041305,
122.74547069], [21.89390815, 24.33770482, 0.0, 130.04213984, 112.98940283,
54.26427666, 71.35378232, 104.72088677, 81.67425703, 90.26668791,
71.13288376, 18.74250061, 109.87223765, 93.96339767, 69.46698314,
84.37362794, 124.38527485, 98.82541733, 116.43603102, 113.07526035],
[108.37048253, 144.67214389, 130.04213984, 0.0, 37.8990613, 111.2161525,
176.70411028, 28.99007398, 149.1355788, 124.17549005, 198.6298252,
126.02950495, 101.55746829, 37.24713176, 152.8114446, 189.29178553,
34.96711005, 180.83483984, 14.33728853, 35.75999058], [91.40006121,
132.28290899, 112.98940283, 37.8990613, 0.0, 111.05881157, 147.27385449,
44.12747289, 115.00173099, 134.19476383, 175.9860033, 104.1315771,
120.19673135, 27.75062658, 120.90347767, 184.88952087, 65.64187459,
183.20903265, 36.35677531, 60.34864715], [49.35063671, 49.12079288,
54.26427666, 111.2161525, 111.05881157, 0.0, 125.59451494, 82.23823276,
129.68328938, 37.23819968, 118.38443321, 68.15130552, 56.84347674,
84.29966837, 120.38742076, 78.30380948, 91.88522811, 72.15031414,
97.00421525, 82.23460459], [82.20983622, 85.34321428, 71.35378232,
176.70411028, 147.27385449, 125.59451494, 0.0, 158.1002588, 45.08950594,
161.43320938, 50.02998891, 59.93581537, 180.43028005, 139.95387244,
30.1390519, 133.42262669, 182.2085151, 158.47101132, 165.61965338,
170.96891788], [83.69080223, 117.39095617, 104.72088677, 28.99007398,
44.12747289, 82.23823276, 158.1002588, 0.0, 136.48099476, 96.57856065,
174.901291, 103.29640959, 77.53059476, 22.95598599, 137.23185588,
160.37639016, 26.14552185, 152.04872054, 14.96145727, 17.29636403],
[80.39436793, 103.60848008, 81.67425703, 149.1355788, 115.00173099,
129.68328938, 45.08950594, 136.48099476, 0.0, 166.89727482, 92.90019808,
63.53459104, 177.66159356, 115.1228903, 16.7609065, 160.79059188,
162.35278463, 179.82760993, 140.44928488, 151.9058635], [86.5204431,
79.67795144, 90.26668791, 124.17549005, 134.19476383, 37.23819968,
161.43320938, 96.57856065, 166.89727482, 0.0, 148.39351779, 105.1934756,
34.72852943, 106.44495924, 157.55442606, 83.19240274, 96.09890812,
61.77726814, 111.24915274, 89.68625779], [91.24484876, 69.52024038,
71.13288376, 198.6298252, 175.9860033, 118.38443321, 50.02998891,
174.901291, 92.90019808, 148.39351779, 0.0, 72.71434547, 175.07913091,
161.59035051, 76.3634308, 96.89392413, 195.433818, 127.21259331,
185.63246606, 184.09218079], [22.32327813, 42.65007733, 18.74250061,
126.02950495, 104.1315771, 68.15130552, 59.93581537, 103.29640959,
63.53459104, 105.1934756, 72.71434547, 0.0, 121.04924013, 88.90999601,
52.48935172, 102.51264644, 125.51831504, 117.54806623, 113.26375241,
114.12813777], [99.5351474, 105.60007249, 109.87223765, 101.55746829,
120.19673135, 56.84347674, 180.43028005, 77.53059476, 177.66159356,
34.72852943, 175.07913091, 121.04924013, 0.0, 93.63052717, 171.17130953,
117.77417844, 69.1477611, 95.81237385, 90.62801636, 65.7996984],
[72.1001264, 110.50120501, 93.96339767, 37.24713176, 27.75062658,
84.29966837, 139.95387244, 22.95598599, 115.1228903, 106.44495924,
161.59035051, 88.90999601, 93.63052717, 0.0, 117.17351252, 159.88686894,
48.89223072, 156.34374083, 25.76186961, 40.13509273], [71.98278813,
89.92218111, 69.46698314, 152.8114446, 120.90347767, 120.38742076,
30.1390519, 137.23185588, 16.7609065, 157.55442606, 76.3634308, 52.48935172,
171.17130953, 117.17351252, 0.0, 145.68608389, 162.51692098, 166.12926334,
142.8970605, 151.6440003], [99.8621559, 60.03623019, 84.37362794,
189.29178553, 184.88952087, 78.30380948, 133.42262669, 160.37639016,
160.79059188, 83.19240274, 96.89392413, 102.51264644, 117.77417844,
159.88686894, 145.68608389, 0.0, 169.4299171, 33.39882791, 175.00707479,
160.25054951], [104.59071383, 133.61394005, 124.38527485, 34.96711005,
65.64187459, 91.88522811, 182.2085151, 26.14552185, 162.35278463,
96.09890812, 195.433818, 125.51831504, 69.1477611, 48.89223072,
162.51692098, 169.4299171, 0.0, 156.08760216, 29.36259602, 11.39668734],
[108.61475753, 76.26668715, 98.82541733, 180.83483984, 183.20903265,
72.15031414, 158.47101132, 152.04872054, 179.82760993, 61.77726814,
127.21259331, 117.54806623, 95.81237385, 156.34374083, 166.12926334,
33.39882791, 156.08760216, 0.0, 167.00907734, 148.3962894], [94.91576952,
130.54041305, 116.43603102, 14.33728853, 36.35677531, 97.00421525,
165.61965338, 14.96145727, 140.44928488, 111.24915274, 185.63246606,
113.26375241, 90.62801636, 25.76186961, 142.8970605, 175.00707479,
29.36259602, 167.00907734, 0.0, 25.82164171], [93.20212636, 122.74547069,
113.07526035, 35.75999058, 60.34864715, 82.23460459, 170.96891788,
17.29636403, 151.9058635, 89.68625779, 184.09218079, 114.12813777,
65.7996984, 40.13509273, 151.6440003, 160.25054951, 11.39668734,
148.3962894, 25.82164171, 0.0]]

=>

[[0.0, 0.0], [41.9519, 0.0], [19.6294, 9.6969], [-88.505, -62.5382],
[-88.0155, -24.6423], [21.2457, -44.5433], [14.7187, 80.8815], [-59.789,
-58.5613], [-29.9331, 74.6141], [34.5297, -79.3315], [62.6017, 66.3826],
[5.2353, 21.7007], [6.1479, -99.3451], [-62.597, -35.7777], [-13.6408,
70.6785], [96.8736, -24.2478], [-61.4216, -84.6558], [92.2547, -57.3257],
[-74.7503, -58.4927], [-55.0613, -75.199]]
```

Comment: So basically you are looking for the inverse function of  `DistanceMatrix` in mathematica ;-)

Comment: In your first example, the third point could be either (3,4) or (3,-4).

Comment: @DavidC You didn't read the assumptions closely enough.

Comment: Yes. I now see.

Comment: Can there be more than one correct answer or am I doing something wrong? I'm getting `+0.322` for the last coordinate of the 2nd example.

Comment: @Emigna As a sanity check, calculate the distances between every point you calculated. You should get the original distance matrix back. If I do that your solution can't be right (assuming that the only difference is the `-0.322` -> `+0.322`). Also make sure you follow the assumptions correctly. Those are necessary to get a unique answer.

Comment: Apparently I'm doing something wrong. I checked the 3rd example as well and all values are correct, but signs are wrong in some places.

Comment: @Emigna Could it be that your third person's y-coordinate is less than zero which has an effect on the other person's coordinate's signs?

Comment: @JonathanFrech: For the 5-person example, only the 5th person gets the wrong sign on the y-coordinate (and the 3rd persons y-coordinate is positive). My current issue is that all y-coordinates are positive, but that is due to some change I've made which I can't recall as I'm pretty sure there were negative y-coordinates before in the 20-people example.

Comment: Can we return a list of x-coordinates and a list of y-coordinates instead of a single list of [x,y]?

Comment: So the third point is `(x,y)` for `y>0` and `x` is unrestricted?

Comment: @Giuseppe Correct.

Comment: @Arnauld I suppose that's fine.

Comment: A matrix method is discussed in [part II.B. of this paper (page 4)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07541.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>74</s></sup> 59 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
+⍣(0>11○3⊃⊢)p÷×2⊃p←0j1⊥2↑⍉⊃⌹∘⍉⍨/1 .5*⍨2↑8415⌶.5×(⊣.+⍨-⊢)×⍨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZjNjl1HFYXH9FOcWdrQ91A/u/4mSEyRDAOGVg9atOOAOrTlWKCMkUww6SgZWGbChAgpT5CIsd/kvoj59q7T7rMvGaNIzr19T1Xtn7XWXnWunt8crj@/url99v5xPL76@vjqm@NXb37129/8@qMnT8IaLhb@KTFfLJH/9zBqr/q3kpvEkLp@7i3GXHK@vFie3D9tS1nSeqihXrCg95pHbfrTiH2MUoYu2G/78PyyHT1qSaMFuYhrblFCHm2esj/fbX2/4H4HkRIih11ePHmIdB@EHnu/936B7XB5@dHZ4/SjdZG4jhJZnuLaRx6hR9bE0NktSE@FU0ZcJYRQY4osGGsuoeba@NLTmsLouabEl7xW1oeUWNPDmofw1NAvdS0piORomyWRLr1Rn5TWnHJqXYs9BvUoURppt7TGEGKq@pkQO8/cP9RrijPjIGsZocXc84y5sro0i1koTWl1FCIbmTATu@Wqdf@Qs1UgyZpzs2TZRGStLUXJXQ/I5NcTSY1hmccU2kidfvWyZsk8qM2LsZFtGKXGpoFQiECGIfBbG2zYOE9IpQ4tRKJL/CJprSWE1rJFX1jEtyR6cAQPpB/4h7PGOlKKPUa@VIKm3jlEC5CjIoUOga61uqZaK/DQFma2kCD8X79R6SZFWqiGV9dtV4EJeRYHSezcRaNJdIBDkta5CKdIapxkvQGJrdPE2Y@WAjhulKFHEpdUWtB2hC20EW0Rle09KwRiX/UphZfuQHsbAGq1WNtGzQBaSUHppFawFomoE3GjCm1oeBp/L6lJ10V9BbUSZ1VjXQFhyJBMv2WoWRLfi5HWofy09fsKWFFyo2aDOG1jYBxrLEmLS@HZJk4mp77yVGis1E0BTS6lKWY00NiKDOtWJNKaQLYiFGyuIY0SZBj94soaqWDPzk0CyKOVq6QVIIiI1W6sacTWiyaQgTysjHN3CNiz9K2D1mFKbs@VtZVBjKVrFRy7PeJ94/f5T5REkz3CKQp7Ic5GI0QRTDEjHeFM26essLnlYLsSaBzS6qRtK5wB9CcL@CmznYoL8Oe52jIFpKyNqENNtfT50whZmkEjAofeYXroChSIJLGDdj2rK/V5NCmgcgWtgLPkSSTqU6msgcHpmqO6A7xvvCvArEkqaJJAd4Wm6mNWcljrElLQAf5Q9mtXc4@DmaEbgcSOQGZtQu1rLMpbRUapaxcyrW3iPrGCXdosQiZPAlUmsgOyEoZ0E1l6nVJXxVAtLVBAlDmj0QlwbfFbeFKDzCHm1XwvcJ7mDu6@7T79WZHSVctT0VoKQKBToRhxK9Aj5WAFKUEZMGgkMRckLxfUyRIFy5I5bSI781sh8aSKCk35Qyj3aigpgZFqrdd0eqGUMwg6HZAAzUAxArSYoZpB04HblUdGCDfHTqV9r3CO6Q7wvu/7AmzyiizRKiUBLWE6QmEMg2kJLEb5R5yDJI0qnM6erTEetXDb4NSp38sklGIpogKmMgpsyMUu@mBdowCkqNqo4oHckUGZojAYmKUlzazpUZnDzAC58e0HmtN1r2@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@nDZ1Lxx5UIJphuPaiF0SIIMaJF1kBm7K1FF9ND8RKOs@Cgtwv5i4l26c6vOsznr4ke4m2Ve1J20eYo7tLvGu9w3k9YoAH2bvAR7TC/@Ux2GY52bRQ4GE3oDaZoE1S1QQmF6HQps0SFbYESz4eAuZP5ysjfp3qp6x@asi5/hfpbtJN0J257jHu3/0/CH7DdZLSpvZGnWtCo56lDjM1UYMYID2QZkUk3mKl/mZIBAYD5vZPhwD3VXMn81cQbd@1Rn2E6sixvhfpadKvpO3TzPHdR9330JtvlL6wBmVLUiGDwNLZ4SrVO9BbzNFhp6x7Arcd6h3B3c3Uf9xcxdT5xJd27V2TbvXtwUd8PMC/te4PYc93A/afwu/c22cgAjLySzUdwOmIiQzO6RlEeHf5b7a@TDiwd3CfeXUX8lczcT59FPzKo3bc68@CHuJ5pTdidvnuke8771rgYbTvQCMXT8yf2URiuHVcK9dDl5AeFv4u4@ur@VufvJiU93ftXbNudfToa5G2pO2p3IebY70PvuuwrMV0hUlxLRZ@PE7nWTf/PiX0G4m7i7j7qbmb@gOKfu/Krzbd7D@Fm@H2lO253Ieao70Lu@u@w/vG08fvHXj9//7Hj37Xn4RYzHt3/Px9d/Ob7@16Pn73549zbx5fnx1dfhD/H4@t9J30re/U0f@PI/xy/@oZ/vvvt5XNbyUz7oz11iOX75/VrevT0/vv52ZefvDrrdu7d8On715j0H6qHPzo53/1x@eX399Hr5@PbFp1cvX/7@j8@Wl7fLp7cvni6/u3l69eLm8@WzT27/vLz8hD/c3r64/uzsT1c3C/Es/8eIz@R492ZQVtavHEcImsD7n5DCq2/Ow5KX8ug8L2GRR@dlkSU8OjscDmf8/jh@@JTsk26lMfzYW@/TF56mWEOdus4PbrrzheABG1EU@QfVRe6ulxf2txD1HfIBJa@S8vbqMIm@7zhw5S0yX5gDrxZ1qqnG9flG5cDMaQyYA3LG9dmeOyT1vnadEhVN4wuTQV93syPixo@2mjBwNApW5KGnSjwFTqhgEEGDnPaUqjuJHZjHeGPbzjKw7ZRfm3k9QDwo0y/gUmUeG0@Znk05qulh1/pczR3N9O4Ag2rZXpLBR3PeB1xIhmJaHlLA12X9I4INg2bWKIe9Izs0te8DOvwX)

<sup>Lots of golfing at various places thanks to @H.PWiz and @ngn.</sup>

Uses the formula shown in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07541.pdf) shared by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144053/distances-to-coordinates#comment353150_144053). The formula on the paper involves [EVD (eigenvalue decomposition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), and fortunately Dyalog APL has its generalized version [SVD(singular value decomposition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). For square symmetric matrix \$M\$ as input, it exactly computes orthonormal \$U\$ and the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues \$\Lambda\$ in \$M=U\Lambda U^T\$.

#### Ungolfed and how it works

```apl
f←{
  m←×⍨⍵                     ⍝ square of distances
  v←1⌷m                     ⍝ first row
  G←.5×v+⍤1⍉m-⍤1⍨v          ⍝ -(m - column v - row v)÷2
            m-⍤1⍨v  ⍝ add v to -m by rows (rank 1)
           ⍉        ⍝ transpose
       v+⍤1         ⍝ add v to that by rows
    .5×             ⍝ halve

  U E←2↑8415⌶G              ⍝ singular value decomposition
        8415⌶G  ⍝ SVD built-in
                ⍝ since G is square and symmetric, it is identical to EVD
                ⍝ and gives orthonormal U, eigenvalue diagonal E,
                ⍝ transpose of V (≡ U), and a boolean indicator for success
      2↑        ⍝ we need only U and E

  pts←0j1⊥⊖(2↑E*.5)+.×⍉U    ⍝ compute pts as shown in the paper
                            ⍝ and convert to complex
           (2↑E*.5)         ⍝ first 2 rows of element-wise sqrt of E
                   +.×⍉U    ⍝ matmul with transposed U
                            ⍝ the resulting matrix is 2-row matrix where
                            ⍝ 1st row is x-coords and 2nd is y-coords
      0j1⊥⊖                 ⍝ compute x+yi for post-processing

  pts←pts×+×2⊃pts     ⍝ rotate by 2nd point's angle reversed
            2⊃pts  ⍝ the 2nd point
           ×       ⍝ signum; unit vector (representing angle)
          +        ⍝ complex conjugate (negation of angle)
      pts×         ⍝ rotate all points by that angle

  +⍣(0>11○3⊃pts)⊢pts  ⍝ mirror w.r.t. x-axis if 3rd point is below x-axis
  +⍣(          )  ⍝ conjugate all points (mirror w.r.t. x-axis) if...
          3⊃pts   ⍝ the 3rd point
       11○        ⍝ its complex part
     0>           ⍝ is negative
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of `⊖`, and change `v+⍤1⍉⍵-⍤1⍨v←1⌷⍵` to `(⍉⊢-⊣⍀)⍣2⊢⍵`

Comment: Although `v-⍉⍵-v←⊣⍀⍵` is maybe simpler

Comment: Save another byte by changing `(2↑E*.5)+.×⍉` to `2↑⍉(E*.5)⌹⍉`, since U is orthonormal

Comment: If `⎕` is fair game, you can get 64 bytes: `+⍣(0>11○3⊃q)⊢q←p÷×2⊃p←0j1⊥2↑⍉(E*.5)⌹⍉⊃U E←2↑8415⌶.5×(⍉⊢-⊣⍀)⍣2×⍨⎕`

Comment: Another golf: `+⍣(0>11○3⊃q)⊢q←` -> `+⍣(0>11○3⊃⊢)`

Comment: `v+⍤1⍉⍵-⍤1⍨v←⊣/⍵` -> `⍵-⍨⊣.+⍨⍵` @Bubbler @H.PWiz

Comment: @H.PWiz .. or `(⍉⊢-⊣⍀)⍣2` -> `(⊣.+⍨-⊢)` in your 64 bytes

Comment: `(E*.5)⌹⍉⊃U E←` -> `⊃⌹∘⍉⍨/1 .5*⍨`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>183</s> <s>178</s> <s>166</s> <s>161</s> <s>160</s> <s>159</s> <s>158</s> 156 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe and 2 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech.*

```python
def f(D):
 X=D[0][1];o=[0,X];O=[0,0];n=2
 for d in D[2:]:y=d[0]**2;x=(y-d[1]**2)/X/2+X/2;y-=x*x;o+=x,;O+=y**.5*(y>d[2]**2-(x-o[2])**2or-1),;n+=1
 return o,O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZhLbxw5EoTv/hUNzEWSSzVMMvmy0HPy3VcDDR0MyN71YSRD9gDS/nnvl6yWxawZDAxL3a0imY@IyGB/e/7x34f7@PPn3ecvhy8X7y/fvTl8PL4/hduT3N48HE9h@Xh788F@h9ub@2N8c/jy8Hi4O3y9P7w/xXe3756Pdzx9dRVvno4Xz9d3rOPN5e8ff49v@X/zfH18unq6eXh7fFpuPrw9Pl9drfnq4vmPu1O0J68vnq4feHnJ64fHa7lcbu7fHuXN4fHzj78e7w8Py4efvx3@9/Xb98Onu7vPd@P8H4@f7r/z4s@v9/8hlB8Ph6fl@fDt09fH72@@PfKBLbi4@nJxOoU1LIdkP/IabpfDabwen@r2QT6/Hp/e3l5e/uMW/MiSloPwu4VeWrHPcqoqITZ73apIyinZni9Pj6UsqS2UUBYWtFZSL9X@1KX1nnO3BfO2r88fzkf3kmOvQRdZUxUNqdftlPl8t/XLgpcdVHMQDrtdTq@RzkHYsS97zwv@vSoqa8/C4ihr66mHJqyQ0NgraIuZM7qsGkIoEoUFfU05lFSqLC2uMfSWSozLoaW1sDzEyJIW1tSVh7q9KWuOQTXJ2CuqNm2V4sS4pphibVS6d2qRRSsp17hKCBKLvSbAxiP2zIGHWomyZRt0zT1USS1tERdW50rEXalKrqVn4uqJICObpWIl/5XwSD/qmlIdmbKH6lpqFE2tL5JIrkUy6n1kLTHUHhudanlNmnjO2iZSSTX0XKRaGFQhkF4Ibamd7SqnKXmUbkWItIdFGteSQ6g1jdAza3gX1dISgEDugR9L62uPUZoIpStETKlTsOglcZBQ4xDoVy1rLKUAC2teYgcNyu@8CDWumrWGMmDq2uyy35DO2qCRjZtaLJHic0akxFk5Q2PlnNEV8Fcb3ds6UWMAvZUSNCFrjbkGa1g4B9ZlYQ1FbS1Z66Wt9pChyjagrxXg1JJHw3pJoNiYQNm0FDAmujTCrVSgdovNgm85Vm22pq1gVWUrqJQV7IUEsewdglFz5L2Rx0PbtXyX/SY8lXp1ohz7Al4pkiN1peTsIht3Y1t5KFQW2p6AJeVcDSsWptSsffRJiLNE8AwwQeQaYs9B@2CcrCzRAuTGqVFBtoxS5biCAFUddetr7FJbJvwEzuGhbHvDuZa0nVs3Wku1LcuU15o7EeZmGJj57GHuGu5y39AhQ@UIJhvWlSgrPVBwSx2FXnDi2AZJDjQjjE0JU7rWshG1Zo4A7xv0@VNiN8QEyPNYqYnaUdFKyKHEkkcRkbmQtA5ICDhoDW6HZgCBPCoNjMPZZlznyWg4SgWMAsmcNvJQm0JR81CBScUcuR3K54bvkt/qETMSpBDcEGlqmIwRNE0i3G@gvRvdrZ2pSWc62D4AsKGGyeS0tFWyMdWkKpe1KWnCHwN7ZAGb1K0AiRyJ0sjHBshI6NqGoNLkGJtJhAlnBvcKW3qlB4B5BD9i0xJ0G1ZeuGc5m4ntMe7avUt9q0ZuJtsxG@4VBNCjwDMLFVwt3TCKkYPBvtNBAs4IXMqI0cgSBGvisA3Pib9lsmZeLBCT9yG/SJ/GCDaKvRu5tEwVtxBocYDzxnzDBpBiUDaSsaHajDqDBG5c7UV81rOZ2w7lc7998mcpRYVokiGfNjEDIS2ewLQD3iLxXbaBEXtRzmbLWhmCVrPzdLS53vJGIsOQQHsOEEMzfGITe66souBHTAhNLBA3ws@bCnSmYq7R0qp2UuIsHM7JTWg3tryCezWbie0xPjd8l/tWjgK4ezW9tqFMbmzUG@eVRNIAU8ztCCUoMA5UlO08JljrIxLQWGC3cdsqUMED5sfKgY9gEjQtQ2AYJtGeHJmpOSGorSP@zPSHxCUNFZiMiZvV89TaK7gTs5nYHuVzv3e5b@VQSEyS5Ns3CyAd5pN0MvDBaJpjf6CQxJ97tOJk8AH/4rCWIFj4OESzTJwHoW2ux4VAaq2xNNGzhil2aDzWrGWF1tZ@ngSvbmx2KH5WT1Nrp99Oy2Zmzxifm71LfNQC1cK3JnMp2/5oMZJou5AKHg@pNnYjR6kgVWGrr/mYqGMw92ylbzJmBT1BnXqiq1BiLSniIELZBkfo8CRs2c/2c2fJJneyn9OvE2sn3k7KZlp7gE@t9pmfRwpTRq2tFlRDe8BxL3hBiK1tFG5YrrhmM8hF9SzGDD@0Xzcxy7CvlE3aiKQkDJCSi5iAkS/4GP2fTPfOhjpL5tyJH9TzzNopuFMzR2yP8bnjuwKMmmAIC/vEOsTZoFntYZyNpVq5QEH9zWKLeQSbhCACKiSbV4PPhZgE8RuGoVJRXBIqON80nPP2LtT5sdma@Ck9T6ydfDshm0ntIT433Od9NmCV5OnYRkUgx5DiH5oLrRp3hRQGPOgKRKkaTKVAB0VppZvXVpukGRrUcc@dr1f@tjEZ750F9W5stiZ@TE8Ty4u3k7GZ1TPGXaN3mZ8lNJuYkeLwnMUYUbr5mk1xER@Anygx3EZ@uZDnbQRAGoCezgz4daN0F6z5suFM985/OjO2sybzmHYT62/aPWmZZ/YMcNfvXfrnGUvTwKOYOBEKloXeDlYZx0INeJc@QkHcGGlZxlcX/ibtbpb@mjVfOGbj7V2os2TencyTeh5ZOwmf5Wxm9QzyfcOn1M92lP0ZbNz9jbQYfuYexBpXQkpj8z3p@Ub466sDf5X210p/wZrvGrPv3ptQb8icOZkHtZtbOw13Yua57YDuW@7yP@PD7gTdhpy@TGKEsetgwvSlifsKYX@fdjfL@Y413zic9975UG/JnD9xA9uNLi/iTtI8v2ek@6677Levfygs5aHBgwjTV0WGwtdvTpb5SwR3n3Y3S3fPslBerxzL5L6dD3WezHsUK87rvF5eB5dTcSdpm@i8kNshfZn67TL/9QXhz/8D)

Uses the first 3 points to calculate the rest. Returns a pair of `x-coords, y-coords` [as allowed in comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144053/distances-to-coordinates/144078#comment353097_144053).

Comment: `O+=[...]` can be `O+=...,` and `o+=[x]` can be `o+=x,`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Doesn't work. Python only allows adding lists to lists. [TIO](https://tio.run/##LY4xj4QgEIV7f8Uk2wCCi@zaSNjK3taEUJigtxYHBr0E9s976F0xM9@8vJeZNe1v78Rx2GmGGXW4LWBQneZG10Z6pTkdjOzPyY10ShQw@wAWFgedFq1pk7LZTYiQUaHEbM7lBd@HuyhzycRUJFH6UkXZlyoRUjUEpZfV4jQyFJnPiDP7wGosXanqAsK0/wQHnvbHDT7LusFo7WSv63sY3Zbhe3Ff@ZHdQ6QJ1nEJW7GGLJwBRGakNa84hcfZmoobCvriS33@Cc0/X6oxGB@/)

Comment: @Pietu1998 I did not mean `o+=x`, but rather `o+=x,`.

Answer (score 5):

### R, 107

```
function(d){y=t(cmdscale(d))
y=y-y[,1]
p=cbind(c(y[3],-y[4]),y[4:3])%*%y/sum(y[,2]^2)^.5
p*c(1,sign(p[6]))}
```

The big head start is on line 1 where I use R's function for Multi-Dimensional Scaling (MDS). The rest is probably inefficient (thanks for making suggestions on how to improve): line 2 translates the data so that the first point is at (0, 0); line 3 rotates the points so that the second point is at (0,x); line 4 flips everything so that the third point is at y>0.

Comment: R has a built-in for this??? Dang.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>202</s> 193 bytes

```js
d=>{for(k=7;(a=d.map((r,i)=>[x=(r[0]**2-r[1]**2+a*a)/2/a,(d[0][i]**2-x*x)**.5*(k>>i&1||-1)],a=d[0][1])).some(([x,y],i)=>a.some(([X,Y],j)=>(Math.hypot(x-X,y-Y)-d[i][j])**2>1e-6));k+=8);return a}
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

d=>{for(k=7;(a=d.map((r,i)=>[x=(r[0]**2-r[1]**2+a*a)/2/a,(d[0][i]**2-x*x)**.5*(k>>i&1||-1)],a=d[0][1])).some(([x,y],i)=>a.some(([X,Y],j)=>(Math.hypot(x-X,y-Y)-d[i][j])**2>1e-6));k+=8);return a}

format = a => a.map(JSON.stringify).join`\n`

console.log(format(f([[0.0,3.0,5.0],[3.0,0.0,4.0],[5.0,4.0,0.0]])))
console.log(format(f([[0.0,0.0513,1.05809686,0.53741028,0.87113533],[0.0513,0.0,1.0780606,0.58863967,0.91899559],[1.05809686,1.0780606,0.0,0.96529704,1.37140397],[0.53741028,0.58863967,0.96529704,0.0,0.44501955],[0.87113533,0.91899559,1.37140397,0.44501955,0.0]])))
console.log(format(f([[0.0,41.9519,21.89390815,108.37048253,91.40006121,49.35063671,82.20983622,83.69080223,80.39436793,86.5204431,91.24484876,22.32327813,99.5351474,72.1001264,71.98278813,99.8621559,104.59071383,108.61475753,94.91576952,93.20212636],[41.9519,0.0,24.33770482,144.67214389,132.28290899,49.12079288,85.34321428,117.39095617,103.60848008,79.67795144,69.52024038,42.65007733,105.60007249,110.50120501,89.92218111,60.03623019,133.61394005,76.26668715,130.54041305,122.74547069],[21.89390815,24.33770482,0.0,130.04213984,112.98940283,54.26427666,71.35378232,104.72088677,81.67425703,90.26668791,71.13288376,18.74250061,109.87223765,93.96339767,69.46698314,84.37362794,124.38527485,98.82541733,116.43603102,113.07526035],[108.37048253,144.67214389,130.04213984,0.0,37.8990613,111.2161525,176.70411028,28.99007398,149.1355788,124.17549005,198.6298252,126.02950495,101.55746829,37.24713176,152.8114446,189.29178553,34.96711005,180.83483984,14.33728853,35.75999058],[91.40006121,132.28290899,112.98940283,37.8990613,0.0,111.05881157,147.27385449,44.12747289,115.00173099,134.19476383,175.9860033,104.1315771,120.19673135,27.75062658,120.90347767,184.88952087,65.64187459,183.20903265,36.35677531,60.34864715],[49.35063671,49.12079288,54.26427666,111.2161525,111.05881157,0.0,125.59451494,82.23823276,129.68328938,37.23819968,118.38443321,68.15130552,56.84347674,84.29966837,120.38742076,78.30380948,91.88522811,72.15031414,97.00421525,82.23460459],[82.20983622,85.34321428,71.35378232,176.70411028,147.27385449,125.59451494,0.0,158.1002588,45.08950594,161.43320938,50.02998891,59.93581537,180.43028005,139.95387244,30.1390519,133.42262669,182.2085151,158.47101132,165.61965338,170.96891788],[83.69080223,117.39095617,104.72088677,28.99007398,44.12747289,82.23823276,158.1002588,0.0,136.48099476,96.57856065,174.901291,103.29640959,77.53059476,22.95598599,137.23185588,160.37639016,26.14552185,152.04872054,14.96145727,17.29636403],[80.39436793,103.60848008,81.67425703,149.1355788,115.00173099,129.68328938,45.08950594,136.48099476,0.0,166.89727482,92.90019808,63.53459104,177.66159356,115.1228903,16.7609065,160.79059188,162.35278463,179.82760993,140.44928488,151.9058635],[86.5204431,79.67795144,90.26668791,124.17549005,134.19476383,37.23819968,161.43320938,96.57856065,166.89727482,0.0,148.39351779,105.1934756,34.72852943,106.44495924,157.55442606,83.19240274,96.09890812,61.77726814,111.24915274,89.68625779],[91.24484876,69.52024038,71.13288376,198.6298252,175.9860033,118.38443321,50.02998891,174.901291,92.90019808,148.39351779,0.0,72.71434547,175.07913091,161.59035051,76.3634308,96.89392413,195.433818,127.21259331,185.63246606,184.09218079],[22.32327813,42.65007733,18.74250061,126.02950495,104.1315771,68.15130552,59.93581537,103.29640959,63.53459104,105.1934756,72.71434547,0.0,121.04924013,88.90999601,52.48935172,102.51264644,125.51831504,117.54806623,113.26375241,114.12813777],[99.5351474,105.60007249,109.87223765,101.55746829,120.19673135,56.84347674,180.43028005,77.53059476,177.66159356,34.72852943,175.07913091,121.04924013,0.0,93.63052717,171.17130953,117.77417844,69.1477611,95.81237385,90.62801636,65.7996984],[72.1001264,110.50120501,93.96339767,37.24713176,27.75062658,84.29966837,139.95387244,22.95598599,115.1228903,106.44495924,161.59035051,88.90999601,93.63052717,0.0,117.17351252,159.88686894,48.89223072,156.34374083,25.76186961,40.13509273],[71.98278813,89.92218111,69.46698314,152.8114446,120.90347767,120.38742076,30.1390519,137.23185588,16.7609065,157.55442606,76.3634308,52.48935172,171.17130953,117.17351252,0.0,145.68608389,162.51692098,166.12926334,142.8970605,151.6440003],[99.8621559,60.03623019,84.37362794,189.29178553,184.88952087,78.30380948,133.42262669,160.37639016,160.79059188,83.19240274,96.89392413,102.51264644,117.77417844,159.88686894,145.68608389,0.0,169.4299171,33.39882791,175.00707479,160.25054951],[104.59071383,133.61394005,124.38527485,34.96711005,65.64187459,91.88522811,182.2085151,26.14552185,162.35278463,96.09890812,195.433818,125.51831504,69.1477611,48.89223072,162.51692098,169.4299171,0.0,156.08760216,29.36259602,11.39668734],[108.61475753,76.26668715,98.82541733,180.83483984,183.20903265,72.15031414,158.47101132,152.04872054,179.82760993,61.77726814,127.21259331,117.54806623,95.81237385,156.34374083,166.12926334,33.39882791,156.08760216,0.0,167.00907734,148.3962894],[94.91576952,130.54041305,116.43603102,14.33728853,36.35677531,97.00421525,165.61965338,14.96145727,140.44928488,111.24915274,185.63246606,113.26375241,90.62801636,25.76186961,142.8970605,175.00707479,29.36259602,167.00907734,0.0,25.82164171],[93.20212636,122.74547069,113.07526035,35.75999058,60.34864715,82.23460459,170.96891788,17.29636403,151.9058635,89.68625779,184.09218079,114.12813777,65.7996984,40.13509273,151.6440003,160.25054951,11.39668734,148.3962894,25.82164171,0.0]])))
```

#### How?

Let ***d<sub>i,j</sub>*** be the input and ***x<sub>i</sub>***, ***y<sub>i</sub>*** be the expected output.

By the challenge rules, we know that:

- For any pair ***(i, j)***: ***d<sub>i,j</sub> = √((x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)² + (y<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>j</sub>)²)***
- ***x<sub>0</sub> = y<sub>0</sub> = y<sub>1</sub> = 0***

We can immediately deduce that:

1. ***x<sub>1</sub> = d<sub>0,1</sub>***
2. ***d<sub>0,j</sub> = √((x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)² + (y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>j</sub>)²) = √(x<sub>j</sub>² + y<sub>j</sub>²)***
   ***d<sub>0,j</sub>² = x<sub>j</sub>² + y<sub>j</sub>²***
3. ***d<sub>1,j</sub> = √((x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)² + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>j</sub>)²) = √((x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)² + y<sub>j</sub>²)***
   ***d<sub>1,j</sub>² = (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)² + y<sub>j</sub>² = x<sub>1</sub>² + x<sub>j</sub>² + 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>j</sub> + y<sub>j</sub>² = d<sub>0,1</sub>² + x<sub>j</sub>² + 2d<sub>0,1</sub>x<sub>j</sub> + y<sub>j</sub>²***

**Computing *x<sub>j</sub>***

By using 2 and 3, we get:

***x<sub>j</sub>² - (d<sub>0,1</sub>² + x<sub>j</sub>² - 2d<sub>0,1</sub>x<sub>j</sub>) = d<sub>0,j</sub>² - d<sub>1,j</sub>²***

Which leads to:

> ***x<sub>j</sub> = (d<sub>0,j</sub>² - d<sub>1,j</sub>² + d<sub>0,1</sub>²) / 2d<sub>0,1</sub>***

**Computing *y<sub>j</sub>***

Now that ***x<sub>j</sub>*** is known, we have:

***y<sub>j</sub>² = d<sub>0,j</sub>² - x<sub>j</sub>²***

Which gives:

> ***y<sub>j</sub> = ±√(d<sub>0,j</sub>² - x<sub>j</sub>²)***

We determine the sign of each ***y<sub>j</sub>*** by simply trying all possible combinations until we match the original distances. We also have to make sure that we have ***y<sub>2</sub> > 0***.

We do that by using the bitmask ***k*** where ***1***'s are interpreted as positive and ***0***'s are interpreted as negative. We start with ***k = 7*** (***111*** in binary) and add ***8*** at each iteration. This way, positive values of ***y<sub>j</sub>*** are guaranteed to be selected for ***0 ≤ j ≤ 2***. (We could start with ***k = 4*** just as well, because ***y<sub>0</sub> = y<sub>1</sub> = 0*** anyway. But using ***7*** prevents [negative zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) from appearing.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it'd be shorter, but the correct way to calculate the sign of __y__ (after the initial 3) for element `k` is to find `p = (x, y)` with two points, set `p' = (x, -y)`, and take a third already-known point `j` and compare distance `d[i][j]` with `dist(p, j)` and `dist(p', j)`. I don't consider negative zeroes an incorrect answer by the way.

Comment: @orlp Removing negative zeros doesn't cost any byte, so it's a purely aesthetic consideration. :-) (And you're right: this method is a rather inefficient fix on an initially non-working solution. But I thought it was still worth posting.)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>227</s> <s>215</s> <s>209</s> <s>176</s> 169 bytes

```r
function(d){x=y=c(0,0)
x[2]=a=d[1,2]
d=d^2
i=3:nrow(d)
D=d[1,i]
x[i]=(D+a^2-d[2,i])/2/a
y[3]=e=sqrt(d[1,3]-x[3]^2)
y[i]=(D-d[3,i]+x[3]^2+e^2-2*x[3]*x[i])/2/e
Map(c,x,y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLbsIwEEX3/oooG2ww4EderuodWzZVd8ZILklRJBTSPNpEVb89tUNTQhaO5869Z0auhqatitfry940Vd55z2vvvS1OTX4tYI0aWJuyvPQw@zQXWJqqzmAjz3X7Bv3DQfvYRz6eSmXLS1430Mc1sh9uC1ciBM4WO/xjU/TdyV6eIMEEgU4xLY1MFcVMg1SmRwZyyZ@K6vplrWA3tnJtjbmWcLcyR7ZOFbMS2rKtAb3iWmay/qga6KxcrzsrHRmyrTFi7dzaVzd5lVkAW7pi6ZiOkoG9KeEJd7hHP8MZeg@PAhdKkQ3Bnj1CyrFH7T8hIkoip4U8DihhibsnMaU85FxjT03uMWojcUIiEmFgE0kScRHFridoIkQYCpeYc@8B72@2iEImYhJgQDc8pgHhIr7NmW/wwJ4SEyIIQkLtNI2Bui87X8MNnuDzxIjQeoHQ8As)

Once upon a time, I took a course in Computational Geometry. I'd like to say that helped, but I clearly learned nothing.

Input is an R matrix, with the output a list of 2-element vectors `(x,y)` (which is closer to the spec *and* saves bytes).

The problem here is, of course, the first three points. Once you fix three points, you can compute all the others based on those.

I just used a bit of algebra to simplify things and then noticed that since I'm only using the first 3 points to solve for the others, this all vectorized very neatly.

[Outgolfed by flodel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144102/67312)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>140</s> <s>139</s> <s>126</s> <s>121</s> <s>118</s> 117 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe.*

```js
/* this line for testing only */ f =
D=>D.map((d,n)=>n>1?(y=d[0]**2,D[n]=x=(y-d[1]**2)/X/2+X/2,y-=x*x,[x,y**.5*(y>d[2]**2-(x-D[2])**2||-1)]):[X=n*d[0],0])
```

```html
<!-- HTML for testing only --><textarea id="i" oninput="test()">[[0.0, 0.0513, 1.05809686, 0.53741028, 0.87113533], [0.0513, 0.0, 1.0780606, 0.58863967, 0.91899559], [1.05809686, 1.0780606, 0.0, 0.96529704, 1.37140397], [0.53741028, 0.58863967, 0.96529704, 0.0, 0.44501955], [0.87113533, 0.91899559, 1.37140397, 0.44501955, 0.0]]</textarea><pre id="o"></pre><script>window.onload=test=function(){try{document.querySelector("#o").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(f(JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#i").value)))}catch(e){}}</script>
```

Works somewhat like my Python answer. Returning `[x,y]` pairs turned out much shorter than separate X and Y lists in JS. Overwrites the argument list, so don't use it as input multiple times.

Comment: @Giuseppe Actually, I can just not score the `f=` and fit it in one. :P

Comment: well I don't know JavaScript so I'm not surprised I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 160 bytes

```
(s=Table[0{,},n=Tr[1^#]];s[[2]]={#[[1,2]],0};f@i_:=RegionIntersection~Fold~Table[s[[j]]~Circle~#[[j,i]],{j,i-1}];s[[3]]=Last@@f@3;Do[s[[i]]=#&@@f@i,{i,4,n}];s)&
```

The program use built-in `RegionIntersection` to calculate intersection point of circles. Program requires exact coordinate to work.

This assumes `RegionIntersection` always make the point with higher y-coordinate the last one in its result if the x-coordinate is equal. (at least it is true on Wolfram Sandbox)

For some reason `RegionIntersection` doesn't work if there is too many circles in its input so I have to process each pair once by using `Fold`.

Demonstrate screenshot:[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `s[[2]]={#[[1,2]],0}` can be replaced with `s[[2,1]]=#[[1,2]]`.